# How to configure/remove fields from the "Configure your new project" when creating a new project template in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn, project-template

How can I remove certain fields from the "**Configure your new project**" when creating a new *project template* in visual studio?

For an example, there is a Framework section where you can choose your Framework.

I within my project template already set the Framework in my .vstemplate file and ProjectTemplate.csproj.

I want to remove this field so the user won't need to select it.

Is there any API or a way to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to remove the RequiredFrameworkVersion element, You can refer to the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/requiredframeworkversion-element-visual-studio-templates?view=vs-2022